# I recently bought a replacement charger for my laptop, but I'm worried about the polarity

Tags: laptop, battery, power, charger

so a couple of weeks ago my original laptop charger blew. So I ordered a new one with the same voltage and amperage. On arrival I noticed that the polarity might be in reverse. The old charger had (+)--(o) -(-) and the new one has (-)- (o)--(+). The negative one isn't directly connected to the center in both.

The Old One:

[image: the old charger]

The New One:

[image: the new charger]

Is it fine if I use this new charger?

Comment: Yes. They are fine. They are the same polarity. That polarity, btw, is pretty much universal. The center pin is positive, and the ring is negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they're the same. If you look *very* closely at the polarity symbols you'll see that in both cases the "+" has a line that goes all the way to the center contact, while the line from "-" only goes to the outer ring.

Or as you yourself wrote, *"The negative one isn't directly connected to the center in both."*

That's what matters for the polarity symbol. The order in which the "+" and "-" appear in the symbol is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

While the drawings differ, they carry the same message: The center pin is  **+**, the outer ring is **-**.

I have yet to see a charger with a different polarity.

Comment: Oh, I have a LOT of AC adapters with negative-center plugs. But they tend to be older. Center-positive seems to be a more recent idea.